# In what order does java sort through files/directories?

Tags: java

I am somewhat new to java and am trying to create a program which loops through and prints out all of the directories that are inside of a specified location. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;


public class main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File[] files = new File("/media/will/External/Movies").listFiles();
        showFiles(files);
    }

    public static void showFiles(File[] files) {
        String name;
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                name = file.getName();
                if (!(name.contains("!")) && name.contains("(") && name.contains(")")) {
                    System.out.println("Directory: " + name);
                }
                showFiles(file.listFiles()); // Calls same method again.
            } else {
                // System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have some checks in there to only print out certain folder names (has to include both "(" and ")" and can't include "!").

A segment of output that I get in the console is this:

```
Directory: The Matrix (1999)
Directory: The Matrix Reloaded (2003)
Directory: The Matrix Revolutions (2003)
Directory: American Pie 1 (1999)
Directory: American Pie 2 (2001)
Directory: American Pie 3 - The Wedding (2003)
Directory: American Pie 4 - Band Camp (2005)
Directory: American Pie 5 - The Naked Mile (2006)
Directory: American Pie 6 - Beta House (2007)
Directory: American Pie 7 - The Book of Love (2009)
Directory: American Pie 8 - Hole In One (2010)
Directory: Borat (2006)
Directory: Casino Royale (2006)
Directory: Despicable Me 2 (2013)
Directory: Elysium (2013)
Directory: Horrible Bosses (2011)
Directory: Finding Nemo (2003)
Directory: Friday Night Lights (2004)
Directory: Full Metal Jacket (1987)
Directory: Gladiator (2000)
Directory: Hannibal (2001)
Directory: Nightcrawler (2014)
Directory: How To Train Your Dragon (2010)
Directory: I Am Legend (2007)
```

From what I can tell, there is no right or reason to the current order that I am I getting the directories returned in. For some parts it seems to be alphabetical, but for other areas it seems to be random.

The end goal is for the output to be alphabetical, however I want to understand why this order is present first.

Thanks!!

Comment: Very likely you are getting the files in the "raw" order returned by the operating system.  I suspect this would initially be chronological (by time of creating the dictionary entry), but would become jumbled more as files were deleted and new ones added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See here :

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html
```

you are calling

```
listFiles
public File[] listFiles()
```

I quote from java docs (the list I provided):

> "There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order."

If you want to sort a file do this :

```
File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(fileList);
```

Answer (score 4):

The order of returning the directories depends on your file system, not on Java. Some file systems always list file names in alphabetical order; others don't. There's not much to understand here; simply sort the files as you need.

Answer (score 2):

It's the order in which the files are stored on the filesystem, which can theoretically be anything, but is most likely be related to the order the files have been created in.